# Has Thursday rescuing Mycroft from Sherlock Holmes shown up in a book?

Tags: thursday-next

In *Lost in a Good Book*, it's established that Thursday's Uncle Mycroft traveled into the Sherlock Holmes series, probably via his Prose Portal.

> “Item three: Interloper in the Sherlock Holmes series by the name of Mycroft—turns up quite unexpectedly in *The Greek Interpreter* and claims to be his brother. Anyone know anything about this?” I shrank lower, hoping that no one would have enough knowledge of my world to know we were related. Sly old Fox! So he had rebuilt the Prose Portal. I covered my mouth to hide a smile.

He is further mentioned in *The Well of Lost Plots*:

> Uncle Mycroft had sought refuge in the Sherlock Holmes series to avoid [Goliath].

Then, in *Something Rotten*, it's mentioned he was rescued.

> He had set up home in the Sherlock Holmes canon to escape Goliath but had remained stuck there until I rescued him about a year ago.

And yet, in *Thursday Next: First Among Sequels*, they still don't have a way into Sherlock Holmes.

> ".... Before bookjumping was developed, every character was marooned in his or her own novel. For many of the books outside the influence of the Council of Genres and Text Grand Central, it’s still like that. *Pilgrim’s Progress* and the Sherlock Holmes series are good examples. We know roughly where they are, due to the literary influence they exert on similar books, but we still haven’t figured out a way in. And until someone does, a bookjump is impossible.”

Was Mycroft's rescue covered in a short story or novella perhaps? I have only had access to the first five books, so I'll admit that I might be missing a flashback in a later book.

Comment: I'm preeetty sure I have copies of *One of Our Thursdays Is Missing* and *The Woman Who Died a Lot* - may have borrowed one from a library - but I won't be able to re-read them in the next 7 days... If I recall, Mycroft continues to play a diminishing part in both remaining books. +1 for picking up that thread, regardless.

Comment: *First Among Sequels* is his final bow. But he was rescued prior to *SOmething Rotten*. It may indeed simply be an offscreen moment, but I could also see it happening in an interquel story.

Comment: Could it be covered in _The Great Samuel Pepys Fiasco_, perhaps?

Comment: @mpez0: It is possible... sad we'll never see it.

Comment: I finished reading *The Woman Who Died A Lot* yesterday. Mycroft is mentioned 3 separate times, but none mentioning his sojourn into Sherlock Holmes, nor even mentioning his prose portal directly. Notably, Thursday does not bookjump at all. One significant plot deals directly with the book world. There is an un-numbered page after the Acknowledgements (it would be page 367 in my copy) which says "Thursday Next returns in TN8: *Dark Reading Matter*". If I recall, however, none of the book titles that are in mentioned in the earlier books end up being the real title of the next book.

Comment: So ***IF*** there is another Thursday Next novel and if it does indeed deal with the Bookworld plot built up in *The Woman Who Died A Lot*, there is a pretty good chance that it will involve Mycroft and his prose portal. (Hope that isn't too much of a spoiler.)